# How to retrieve value from query string with AngularJS

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I got alot of progress in my previous project and needed a final piece of help i just cant seem to get.

I build my whole angular controller with all the data that needs to populate on the page, but i need to filter by a specific value  being passed from another page.

I decided to do query string, but i am lost how to retrieve my 2 parameters, 1 being used in this section, 1 being used further down the page. I tried using jquery url (project) but in the jquery call i can't connect it to the angular scope object.

How do i use the resource or the location provider correctly to accomplish this?

url example:http://localhost/Client/activitysubpage.asp?activity=6&day=1
Note:earlier in the page i call the ng-app and the ng-controller directives.

I have the angular library as well as the jquery library loaded.
//What i made to grab the url item
uses url.js

```
<script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
           var myactivity =url('?activity');
           var myday = url('?day');
          $scope.currentactivity = myactivity;

//I tried saving the value to a input variable and using ng-bind but it doesnt see the initial value.
// $("#activityitem1").val(myactivity);
        });
                            </script>

<input ng-model="currentactivity" id="activityitem1">
   <h1>NG-MODEL VALUE IS {{currentactivity}}</h1>
 <div class="item item-bg-center-contain">
    <div ng-repeat="items in activities  | filter:{id : myactivity }:true">
          <img ng-src="assets/images/activities/headers/{{items.id}}.jpg" class="img-responsive" style="width:100%;height:auto;" />
    </div>


//controller/instantiation code
 var myapp = angular.module("ActivitySelection", []);


            myapp.controller("ActivityController", function ($scope) {
$scope.shortdates = ["Thursday, January 28","Friday, January 29","Saturday, January 30"];
$scope.currentactivity = 1;
                $scope.activities =
                 [{
    "id":1,
    "title":"Activity1"},

{
    "id":2,
    "title":"Activity2"},
......
{
    "id":8,
    "title":"Activity8"}
];
```

Comment: thanks for the help.

my next q is in a js object literal how do i pull back a url ,

for instance...
"blurb": [
    "<a href=\"http://www.google.com\" target=\"_blank\">Googlw<\/a>A comfortable drive ...]

renders on the screen as :

<a href="http://www.google.com" target="_blank">Googlw</a>A comfortable drive

and it should be a link

Answer (score 2):

you can use $location service of angularJS  for the same

```
myapp.controller("ActivityController", function ($scope,$location) {
  var myParam=$location.search().YOUR_SEARCH PARAM
  //use myParam however you want.
```

see [$location angular docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$location) for more info

Comment: I tried your idea i get the following error.

'code'
TypeError: $location.query is not a function
    at new <anonymous> (activities_controller.js:6)
    at Object.invoke (angular.js:4473)
    at extend.instance (angular.js:9093)
    at nodeLinkFn (angular.js:8205)
    at compositeLinkFn (angular.js:7637)
    at compositeLinkFn (angular.js:7641)
    at publicLinkFn (angular.js:7512)
    at angular.js:1660
    at Scope.$eval (angular.js:15878)
    at Scope.$apply (angular.js:15978)

'code'

Comment: 'code'

            myapp.controller("ActivityController", function ($scope,$location) {
$scope.shortdates = ["Thursday, January 28","Friday, January 29","Saturday, January 30"];
var myparam=$location.query().activity;

Comment: Sorry .. My bad it should be $location.search() .. Updated the answer

Comment: let me try to implement

Comment: '$scope.activityparam=$location.search().activity;
<h1>ActivityParam{{activityparam}}</h1>
 <div class="item item-bg-center-contain">
    <div ng-repeat="items in activities  | filter:{id : activityparam}:true">
          <img ng-src="assets/images/activities/headers/{{items.id}}.jpg" class="img-responsive" style="width:100%;height:auto;" />
    </div>'

what did i do wrong?

Comment: i tried using var and didnt understand how to retrieve it

Comment: does the url contain `?activity=value`  ?  and try to log `$scope.activityparam` and see the output

Comment: returns undefined

 $scope.activityparam=$location.search().activity;
console.log("-------------------");
console.log($scope.activityparam);
console.log("-------------------");

Comment: got it working apparently the url needs to be of type 
activitysubpage.asp#?activity=6&day=6.

Comment: do u need # due to asp?

Comment: yes. i do.

 
thanks for the help. my next q is in a js object literal how do i pull back a url , for instance... "blurb": [ "<a href=\"google.com\" target=\"_blank\">Googlw<\/a>A comfortable drive ...] renders on the screen as : <a href="google.com"; target="_blank">Googlw</a>A comfortable drive and it should be a link

Comment: that in itself a different question. you can look into javascript eval() and angular directive templates in combination  to get desired effect

Answer (score 0):

I have just created a plunk for you. please go through this.

[How to get query string parameters](http://embed.plnkr.co/ZI6MtKnGTRyJXzX4wcp8/preview)

This example is based upon ngRoute angular's default routing library. Let me know if you require ui-router example.

Note: In this example I have use $route to get the parameters. The reason is 
that the $routeParams are only updated after a route change completes successfully. This means that you cannot rely on $routeParams being correct in route resolve functions. Instead you can use $route.current.params to access the new route's parameters.

Hope this helps!.

Comment: Please post your answer *here*.

Comment: thank you for the idea abhishek but i wanted to use something more basic like the http property

Comment: i mean the $location object but i am having trouble retrieving it from on top